# Trying to have two different x-axis spacings in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis

I am trying to condense the spacing of my plot to read my x-axis as (0,25) with a spacing interval of 25 so that the first value is at 25. Then after 25, I want the spacing to be separated by a value of 10. Attached is a graph that, scatter plot with different x-axis spacing, I am trying to replicate with my data.

[image: scatter plot with two x-axis spacing]

Here's the code that I am currently using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DepthMax, y=Duration, color=Shape)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=5, linetype =5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

Comment: ```scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0, 25, seq(35, max(data$DepthMax), 10)))```? Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: @M-- You probably mean `scale_x_continuous`?

Comment: @stefan yup, using my phone late at night should be reserved for X (formerly known as Twitter).